# phonegap build problems (android)

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

When I try to build my app, using Linux ElementaryOS (Ubuntu 12.04 (I think?)) I get thousands of errors saying:

```
rm: could not remove file (code EACCESS)
```

The results of the following show:

```
$ phonegap -v
3.5.0-0.20.4

$ cordova -v
3.5.0-0.2.4

$ ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Any suggestions? I've been battling through several errors for about a week now :(

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Update I just changes the permissions of platforms/android too 777 (not a great solution I know). It's now giving me the following:

```
[Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets] { [Error: /var/www/ppl/app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2] code: 2 } –
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after much pain and anguish... I figured it out.

1). I installed ANT after I installed ionic/cordova/phonegap etc, the best order to install everything in is, java, ant, then cordova/phonegap/ionic.

2). I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu, if you are using the same then you need to install several android 32-bit libs.

3). I deleted the entire project (apart from my css, added js files and my html templates), created a new one using `$ ionic start test-app` then I ran `$ ionic platform add android` then ran `$ ionic run android` and it worked.

4). Make sure your paths are correct in ~/.bashrc mine look as followed:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ewan/adt-bundle/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ewan/adt-bundle/platform-tools
```

Here's a video that helped me, especially with the 32-bit libs. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEQIwKK7YjY

Don't give up, it's worth it in the end. Best of luck!